# Passing a value from one function to another function in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 functions getLocation() and getLocationName().

The getLocation() function executes an XMLHttpRequest and I wish to pass the response to the getLocationName() function in order to display it in a list.

```
getLocationName = (location) => {
    var locName = location;
    console.log("location name", locName)
    return locName;
}

getLocation = (lat, lon) => {
    var text;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=jsonv2&accept-language=sr-Latn&limit=3&q=" + lat + "," + lon;
    console.log("url: ", url)
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
            var resp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);                
            text = resp[0].display_name;
            console.log("response: ", text);
            this.getLocationName(text);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I can see the response in the console.log() from getLocation, but I get

> Uncaught TypeError: this.getLocationName is not a function

I tried calling it without "this." tried to bind it in the constructor like this

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.getLocationName = this.getLocationName.bind(this);
}
```

Also tried calling it this way:

```
() => this.getLocationName(text);
```

No luck unfortunately...

Comment: There's your problem: `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){}`. Either turn it into an arrow function or `function(){}.bind(this)`

Comment: "this" refers to the request in the callback; that's why you can refer to "this.readystate". It can't refer to two different things. It'd be easier if you weren't using old Ajax techniques; is there a specific reason you're not using fetch/axios/etc?

Comment: @Martin That would break the binding for the status check, no?

Comment: @DaveNewton Ah yes. Didn't see that. Well, as you have written the OP has to make up his mind about how to issue requests. I don't think handling XMLHttpRequest manually is the recommended solution nowadays.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the heads up. I'm an absolute noob, so I'll need to learn about the proper way to handle these requests. I'll look into fetch and axios, thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is about 'this'. "xmlhttp" object has its own 'this'.
Try this:

```
getLocation = (lat, lon) => {
    var that = this; //save this
    var text;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=jsonv2&accept-language=sr-Latn&limit=3&q=" + lat + "," + lon;
    console.log("url: ", url)
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
            var resp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);                
            text = resp[0].display_name;
            console.log("response: ", text);
            that.getLocationName(text);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: I thought `this.readyState` here, `this` is the object of xmlhttp, (i.e., inner `this`) so it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var resp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);                
            text = resp[0].display_name;
            console.log("response: ", text);
            this.getLocationName(text);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. 
The error message no longer shows up, but the getLocationName function does not execute. 
I added a console.log("getLocationNameFunction called") to it so I can see if it runs, but it won't show up.

Comment: sorry mine didn't work. Just remember that in react, normal functions might change the meaning of 'this'

Comment: No problem, I appreciate that you tried to help!

Comment: @JS-Skipper It's nothing to do with React per se, it's how `this` works in JS. `this` can't refer to two different things as this code implies--`this` is the Ajax request, it cannot also be the component instance.

Comment: @Dave Newton Yes, thanks for reminding me.